# FIND_IN_SET on columns? Does it make sense?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, find-in-set

I stumbled across a strange expression, which doesn't make sense to me at all.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('string', `column`);
```

Why not:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='string';
```

I thought FIND_IN_SET is used to find strings in comma-separated string lists. Are there cases where I can benefit from a "FIND_IN_SET"-column expression instead of a simple WHERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET` is usually used other way around: to find a column value from comma separated parameter list as storing values in database as comma separated lists is not usually a good idea:

```
select * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`column`, '1,2,3,4,5');
```